# How to dynamically add the day to deliverydate when iterating list using java 8?

Tags: java-8

I am working on the delivery date shipment. In that we have delivery date according to the postcode. I have to check that list of holiday date with  delivery date if the delivery date is on holiday I should add one more day to that date and show. I have tried but I could not sorted out. It does not return proper value.

This is what I have tried I don't know why i got downvote?

```
List<Date>dateList=xyzService.getAllHolidays();//list of date from the service
dateList.forEach(date -> {
    if (DateUtils.isSameDay(date,expectedDeliveryDate.toDate())){
        expectedDeliveryDate.plusDays(1);
    }

});
```

In above code not getting updated since it is immutable @Misha said.
I have the requirement to check holidays with deliverydate

For **e.g** if expectedDeliveryDate is today if today(31.05.2016) and tomorrow(01.06.2016) is in holiday list i should have get 02.06.2016 as `expectedDeliveryDate`

Comment: New java time classes are immutable.  Calling `plusDays(1)` doesn't change the existing object.  It returns the new object with 1 day added.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish so I can only give you some general guidance.  How many times are you supposed to print out the date?  Your current code will print it as many times as there are holidays.

Comment: @Misha I  know that but i have to update and check with the date. if i add one more day also we should check whether that to have holiday?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do and why do you use `forEach`? Surely you want to do more than print the dates.

Comment: @Tunaki ok . i have a requirement to check delivery date is on holiday. if holiday is continuous 2 days  then we should check that reason i have the `forEach`

Comment: @Tunaki even if add the delivery date also if `plus 1`day is holiday that too i have to check

Comment: what is the type of `expectedDeliveryDate`?

Comment: @Misha don't consider print i want to check dynamically delivery date is even if a add `plus 1` also  holiday ?please give me any suggestion.

Comment: @Misha `org.joda.time.LocalDate`

Comment: Are you using `java.time` or joda time?

Comment: With minimal changes to your existing code, `for (date : dateList) {  if (....) { expectedDeliveryDate = expectedDeliveryDate.plusDays(1);}}`  but you really should avoid `Date` class and consider migrating to `java.time` to avoid confusion due to class names

Comment: I wanted to achieve with java 8 .and also i can't change the model `Date` to 'LocalDate'. since it is migration project any way thanks for the spending valuable time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i fixed the issue:

```
 for (Date date:dateList){
            if (DateUtils.isSameDay(date,expectedDeliveryDate.toDate())){
                expectedDeliveryDate=expectedDeliveryDate.plusDays(1);
            }
        }
```